# Laravel Manager assign's target to user and and user do sales against target within target duration i want to get data of sales according to targets

Tags: laravel, salesforce, target

Laravel Manager assign's target to user and and user do sales against target within target duration i want to get data of user's sales according to targets and also i have filters of weekly monthly and yearly

relation of user with targets

```
   public function targets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Target::class,'Target_users','user_id','target_id');
    }
```

relation of target with user's

```
  ######  Relation With user  ####
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'Target_users','target_id','user_id');
}
```

relation of user with sales

```
   ############ Relation With Sales #############

public function salescommon()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SaleCommon::class,'user_id','id');
}

########             #######################
```

sales common has relation with user

```
 public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id');
}
```

and sales Common is common modle like sales id and user id
and then sales common id goes to different sales modules like doorknock leadgenerations appraisals

```
public function leadgenerations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(LeadGeneration::class,'property_id','id');
}

public function Appraisals()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Appraisals::class,'property_id','id');
}
```

i want to get date of users sales according to targets i mean targets within targets duration the frontend image i have show below

```
https://ibb.co/QnyXpx8
```